# Hiding JPEG Image path - not working

Tags: php, jpeg, content-type

I am trying to hide the actual path of my image using the following piece of code:

```
11> $img = "http://mp4mobilemovies.net/screenshots/Badlapur - DvdScr.jpg";
12>
13> $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
14> 
15> header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
16>
17> imagejpeg($im);
```

But I get nothing, nothing in the sense of not even garbage ASCII, just blank.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

The following errors occurred:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatefromjpeg(http://mp4mobilemovies.net/screenshots/Badlapur - DvdScr.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in <b>/home/vhosts/www.example.com/img.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/vhosts/www.example.com/img.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
```

Comment: Have you set error reporting on at the top of your file? That should get you some errors. Could you also place the `imagecreatefromjpeg()` method in your question?

Comment: Added the errors along with corresponding line numbers.

Comment: The error log shows you exactly what the problem is. 

It fails to open the image file 'failed to open stream: HTTP request failed' which returns boolean false instead of an actual resource for the image.

Comment: I can easily do `<img src...` with the given url, then what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe they have some kind of protection, browser detection or something..

Comment: See [1st example](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) on php.net. Make sure your server configuration allows [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) to [load contents from remote source](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Comment: I have already done the same with png images with no error.

Comment: Also please provide the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where the mistake was, I was actually getting the `$img` variable via an XPath Query rather than simple typing it, so I had to use `strval($img)` and use `str_replace()` to replace the spaces with `%20` instead of `urlencode()` which would conert the other characters as well. But thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid doing this. Main reason is that PHP will make a call to a remote source, then load image and serve it to users. If you **must** do this, I suggest you use some caching mechanism.

The error thrown by php basically says you're trying to get a remote file that does not exist. Please make sure you've entered the full path correctly.

Also, try replacing blanks with `%20` like this:

`http://mp4mobilemovies.net/screenshots/Badlapur%20-%20DvdScr.jpg`

Now it should work.

Comment: <?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); echo get_file_contents("http://mp4mobilemovies.net/screenshots/Badlapur%20-%20DvdScr.jpg"); //also should use curl, as curl is much faster than file_get_contents with http on PHP, at least prior to 5.6, as PHP doesnt care about content-length header, but wait until connection close, while curl will only read until content-length, which can be several hunded times faster depending on server/connection settings.

Comment: he should avoid making a special purpose proxy? why?

Comment: @hanshenrik this operation is not for high traffic websites